# Print the syncml payload to a xml file

Tags: java, xml, syncml

I want to print the syncml payload in a xml file before using it. Is there a method in java to print the syncml payload into a xml file or a way to check the payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by converting it to a string. (able to find more details from --> http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=26060)

public void printXML(Document request){

```
    try
    {
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(request);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);

        String checkpayload = writer.toString();
        System.out.print(checkpayload);
    }
    catch(TransformerException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```